Resetting option setPendingIntentBackgroundActivityStartMode to SYSTEM_DEFINED from the options provided by the pending intent creator because this
in a JobService on Android in background
Intent intent = new Intent( this, StreamListMainActivity.class );
ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeBasic();
options.setPendingIntentBackgroundActivityStartMode( ActivityOptions.MODE_BACKGROUND_ACTIVITY_START_ALLOWED );
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( context, 998, intent, FLAG_IMMUTABLE, options.toBundle() );
try
{
    pendingIntent.send();
}
catch ( PendingIntent.CanceledException e )
{
    AppLogger.Exception( LOG_TAG, e );
}

I have this message error :

Resetting option setPendingIntentBackgroundActivityStartMode(1) to SYSTEM_DEFINED from the options provided by the pending intent creator (com.Myapp) because this option is meant for the pending intent sender

Thanks
